# Single private repository/branch?

Tags: git, github

I am new to `Github`, and working on a software that I would prefer stay private.
Is the only way to hide my files from public is by paying ?

I am not connected to other users, obviously, so what are the chances that strangers can find this code/branch/class ?

Is there any simple way to hide only a single repo/branch or even make it more private ?

Is there a good alternative using Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the only way to hide my files from public is by paying ?

This is GitHub's business model.

You can always use `git` on your local computer and manually sync repos between machines on a peer-to-peer basis, but if you want to use GitHub for hosting your repos privately then you'll have to pay $7/mo to store as many private repos as you want. I think it's a good deal.

However, note that both [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing) do offer free prviate git repo hosting, with limits.

> I am not connected to other users, obviously, so what are the chances that strangers can find this code/branch/class ?

They're listed on your profile page as public repos you own.

> Is there any simple way to hide only a single repo/branch or even make it more private ?

You cannot hide branches in git, this is by design.

> Is there a good alternative using Xcode?

Xcode has nothing to do with git or GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, just as a side note, GitLab and BitBucket are popular enough among developers (or are here to stay), or Github is the obvious choice of developers?

Comment: @Curnelious It doesn't matter: they all share compatibility with `git` (and GitHub does not own `git`). GitHub is the most popular repo host by far, but as Microsoft recently purchased GitHub there was a movement to move people and projects over to GitLab and BitBucket, but I liken them to people who they'll move to Canada whenever the US elects a controversial president.